# What is the meaning of Java option -D without value?

Tags: java, arguments

In a project, I saw java option like `-DadminSvr1` which does not has a value. How can I utilize this?

When I searched for usage of java option, all that I found was options with values.
It says that if I pass `-DadminSvr1="C:\test"`, I can get the value in java code as follow.

```
System.getProperty("adminSvr1");
```

What about `-DadminSvr1`? Can I still get a boolean value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `System.getProperty()` says:

> **Returns:** the string value of the system property, or null if there is no property with that key.

If you use `-D` with no value, you will get an empty string from `getProperty`. This is a different value than a `null` return value.